# curl replacement for 'wget -O' or how to define targetfiles with curl

Tags: curl, wget

I have a problem using curl. I want to have a replacement with curl for

```
wget -O file
```

or

```
wget --output-document=file
```

I have seached the manpages and google and did not find a proper replacement.
or does somebody know how to define targetfiles in curl

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple, simple.

```
curl http://google.com >output.html
```

or

```
curl -o output.html http://google.com/
```

(And I am sure reading `curl --help` would have taken less time than prepping a Q on SO.)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didn't know how i could overread this options